# Why am I getting a 500 status error even when successfully posting to my Mongo Database?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, next.js, http-status-code-500

Im working on a personal project and am a third semester student, trying to learn web development.
Im using Next.js, Node.js, React, and MongoDB. Ive managed to figure out most solutions to troubles I was having but this is stumping me hard!
I have a simple page that takes a username and comment, and sends it to my mongoDB. This works, as when I check the database it is correctly added. However, no matter what I seem to do I just get a generic HTTP 500 internal server error.

Here is my three pieces of code that are working together:
App/api/sendComment/route.js:

```
// Import the necessary modules
import clientPromise from "../../lib/mongodb";

async function handler(req, res) {
  

  // Ensure that the request method is POST
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    try {
      // Get the username and comment from the request body
      
      const client = await clientPromise;
      const { username, comment } = await req.json();
      // Connect to the MongoDB database
      const db = client.db("comments");
      // Validate that both username and comment are provided
      if (!username || !comment) {
        return res
          .status(400)
          .json({ error: "Username and comment are required" });
      }

      // Insert the comment into the "comments" collection
      const result = await db.collection("UserComments").insertOne({
        username: username,
        comment: comment,
      });
      await client.close();
      // Respond with the inserted comment
      return res.status(200).json({ success: true, comment: result.ops[0] });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error handling comment submission:", error);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
    }
    finally {
      await client.close();
    }
  } else {
    // Respond with an error for unsupported HTTP methods
    return res.status(405).json({ error: "Method Not Allowed" });
  } 
}

export { handler as POST, handler as GET, handler as PUT, handler as DELETE };
```

App/projects/database/page.js:

```
"use client";
// Import the necessary modules
import { useState } from "react";

export default function CommentPage() {
  // State to hold the input values
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [comment, setComment] = useState("");

  const data = { username, comment };
  // Function to handle form submission
  // Function to handle form submission
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      // Send a POST request to the API route with the username and comment
      const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/sendComment", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
      });

      // Check if the HTTP response is not OK
      if (!res.ok) {
        // Throw an error with the HTTP status included in the message
        throw new Error("HTTP status " + res.status);
      }

      // Handle successful submission
      console.log("Comment submitted successfully");
      // Optionally, you can redirect or show a success message here
      // Fetch existing comments again after submitting a new comment
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle submission error
      console.error("Error submitting comment:", error.message);
      // Optionally, you can show an error message here
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Comment Page</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Username:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={username}
            onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
          />
        </label>
        <br />
        <label>
          Comment:
          <textarea
            value={comment}
            onChange={(e) => setComment(e.target.value)}
          />
        </label>
        <br />
        <button type="submit">Submit Comment</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And finally, App/lib/MongoDB.ts:

```
// Import the MongoClient class from the mongodb library
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

// Check if the MONGODB_URI environment variable is set
if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error('Invalid/Missing environment variable: "MONGODB_URI"');
}

// Retrieve the MongoDB URI from the environment variable
const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;

// Define options for the MongoClient (can be customized as needed)
const options = {};

// Declare variables to store the MongoClient instance and its promise
let client;
let clientPromise: Promise<MongoClient>;

// Check if the application is in development mode
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  // In development mode, use a global variable to preserve the MongoClient
  // instance across module reloads caused by Hot Module Replacement (HMR)
  if (!global._mongoClientPromise) {
    // Create a new MongoClient instance with the provided URI and options
    client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
    // Connect to the MongoDB server and assign the promise to the global variable
    global._mongoClientPromise = client.connect();
  }
  // Use the global promise for the MongoClient
  clientPromise = global._mongoClientPromise;
} else {
  // In production mode, create a new MongoClient instance and connect to the server
  client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
  clientPromise = client.connect();
}

// Export a module-scoped MongoClient promise.
// By doing this in a separate module, the client can be shared across functions.
export default clientPromise;
```

So far, Ive tried removing and switching around the various error codes, as well as removing them entirely.

As well, when I deploy to Vercel, my server logs indicate "Error handling comment submission: TypeError: r.status is not a function
at handler (/var/task/.next/server/app/api/sendComment/route.js:1:930)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.prod.js:14:39748"

But I cant seem to figure out just how to fix this. Im guessing this might be the cause of the 500 issue, but I can't be certain. Im still a bit of a beginner, and this was an optional project my teacher recommended as I was doing well in his class.

Comment: Try removing `await client.close();` from `try` block on your server code.